# Pass value with Spring Expression

Tags: spring-el

Any idea if you can pass with Spring Expression a value to the field of an object from a property? This is the closer I got. backoff is of type long. For autoCreateTopics this works.
​​​​​​​

```
 @RetryableTopic(
      autoCreateTopics = "#{@kafkaProperties.autoCreateTopics}",
      backoff = @Backoff(delay = "#{ T(java.lang.Long).parseLong(@kafkaProperties.backoff)}"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@BackOff.delayExpression`

```java
/**
 * An expression evaluating to the canonical backoff period. Used as an initial value
 * in the exponential case, and as a minimum value in the uniform case. Overrides
 * {@link #delay()}. Use {@code #{...}} for one-time evaluation during initialization,
 * omit the delimiters for evaluation at runtime.
 * @return the initial or canonical backoff period in milliseconds.
 * @since 1.2
 */
String delayExpression() default "";
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure why you are having difficulty, it works as expected for me.

```
logging.pattern.console=%d [%t] %m%n
logging.level.root=off
logging.level.com.example.demo=info

spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So76201250Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So76201250Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so76201250", "test");
        };
    }

}

@Component
class MyBean {

    public long getAttempts() {
        return 4;
    }

    public long getDelay() {
        return 10_000;
    }

}

@Component
class Listener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Listener.class);

    @KafkaListener(id = "so76201250", topics = "so76201250")
    @RetryableTopic(attempts = "#{@myBean.attempts}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{@myBean.delay}"))
    void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        log.info(in + " from " + topic);
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @DltHandler
    void handle(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        log.info(in + " from " + topic);
    }

}
```

```
2023-05-09 10:44:22,498 [so76201250-0-C-1] test from so76201250
2023-05-09 10:44:32,504 [so76201250-retry-0-0-C-1] test from so76201250-retry-0
2023-05-09 10:44:42,510 [so76201250-retry-1-0-C-1] test from so76201250-retry-1
2023-05-09 10:44:52,517 [so76201250-retry-2-0-C-1] test from so76201250-retry-2
2023-05-09 10:44:53,027 [so76201250-dlt-0-C-1] test from so76201250-dlt
```

If you can't figure it out, post a similar reproducer so I can see what's wrong.

Comment: actually the behavior is different.. I want it to run every 5 minutes for 4 times, and it was running every 10 minutes and not each time same interval. I created a RetryTopicConfiguration in the end with 
 FixedBackOffPolicy policy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    policy.setBackOffPeriod(properties.getBackoff()); and this worked.

Comment: But your question shows a SpEL expression on the `delay` property, which is a long, so that won't compile. The expression should work; if you can provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits the behavior, I can take a look to see what's wrong.

Comment: yeah, the expression is correct. I thought it's still possible to assign it, even if its Long, but as I read in the documentation you can't assign a value using properties for delay.

Comment: Oh, right, makes sense. I was just thinking about spring-retry usage (the same annotation was used here). In fact, my comment about runtime evaluation is incorrect in this context, it only applies when being used in spring-retry.

Comment: Anyway, it would be nice to have the delay as well as a String, it's not very intuitive to use this
FixedBackOffPolicy policy = new FixedBackOffPolicy(); policy.setBackOffPeriod(properties.getBackoff());

Comment: I am not sure why you are having problems; it works fine for me without a `RetryTopicConfiguration`. See my edit.